# Meaning of "as" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, as

What is the exact difference in the meaning between these sentences:

> The intercepted arc might be thought of **as** the part of the circle which is inside the inscribed angle.

and

> The intercepted arc might be thought of the part of the circle which is inside the inscribed angle.

What is the role of "as" in the sentence?

Comment: *The intercepted arc might be thought of the part of the circle which is inside the inscribed angle* (no *as*) sounds like broken English to me.

Comment: Here in this case I think we can't omit *as*. You can also use *to be* there, but then you have to drop *of*. But sentences like - *They thought religion good.* is also spoken without the need of **as**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As as a preposition is also used to say what a person considers a person or thing is. For example, I regard or think of him as my friend.

According to Oxford Dictionary, 'think of as' is a phrasal verb that implies to consider someone or something in a particular way. For example, I think of this place as my home.

When you use the verbs regard or think of in the said sense, you must use the structure regard/think if + object +as.  However, you don't usualky use the preposition as after consider. For example I consider him (to be) the best actor.

Comment: There was an interesting shift between using **as** and **to be** in passive voice: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+considered+as%2Care+considered+to+be%2C+is+considered+as%2C+is+considered+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20considered%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20considered%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20considered%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20considered%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Cardinal, yes,, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

"As" is a preposition here. [According to the Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as),

> We use **as** with a noun to refer to the role or purpose of a person or thing:
>   *I worked **as** a waiter when I was a student. Most of us did.*
>   *The Daily Telegraph appointed Trevor Grove **as** its Sunday editor.*
>   *Internet shopping is seen **as** a cheaper alternative to shopping on the high street.*

Wiktionary [describes it thus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Preposition):

> In the role of.  
>   *What is your opinion **as** a parent?‎*

Comment: Do you mean that "The intercepted arc might be thought of the part of the circle which is inside the inscribed angle" is wrong sentence ?                         Do you mean that "The intercepted arc might be thought of as the part of the circle which is inside the inscribed angle" is only right sentence?

Comment: @user37175 - I'm not sure. It could be passable, but I like the first sentence better. I'm not sure when we can (or cannot) omit the preposition "as".

Comment: // Do you mean that the meaning of each of the sentences are equal to each other?

Comment: @user37175 No. The sentences are **not** equivalent in meaning. The sentence "The intercepted arc might be thought of the part of the circle which is inside the inscribed angle" is not grammatically correct. It is meaningless. A native English speaker would not be able to make sense of it. Without the preposition "as," the relationship between the clauses is not discernible.

Comment: What is the exact difference in the meaning between "The intercepted arc might be thought of as the part of the circle" and  "The intercepted arc might be thought as part of the circle" ?

Comment: @user37175 - you mean, with and without "the"? That's a separate issue. You might ask a separate question.

Comment: @P.E.Dant What about [bala bala] might be thought of something {which is} inscribed in a circle. ? I mean does the structure **be + thought of + sth** is ungrammatical ?